# Merging JavaScript JSON objects with matching parms

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, nativescript

I am having difficulties with finding a solution to "merge" two JSON objects. I could not find any answer that helped. I have two objects and want to compare them and if there is a match, add attribute as a marker to the first object. Here is an example:

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aunzyfcj/

**First input object:**

```
    var firstInput = [{
        "id": "43", 
        "published": "yes", 
        "publish_date": "20.08.2019"

      }, {
        "id": "44",
        "published": "yes", 
        "publish_date": "20.08.2019"         
     }]
```

**Second input object:**

```
    var secondInput = [{
        "id": 92,
        "id_artikla": "140"
    }, {
        "id": 93,
        "id_artikla": "139"
    }, {
        "id": 94,
        "id_artikla": "44"
    }, {
        "id": 95,
        "id_artikla": "10"
    }, {
        "id": 96,
        "id_artikla": "12"
    }, {
        "id": 97,
        "id_artikla": "22"
    }, {
        "id": 98,
        "id_artikla": "9"
    }]
```

I would like to check if `"id": "44"` from `firstInput` Object exist in the "list" of `secondInput` Object and create third `output` Object with copy of (same lenght) `firstInput`. But this time with added attribute `"status": "SAVED"` if `"id": "44"` exists in secondInput as `"id_artikla": "44"`.

If there is no match, I would like to add attribute `"status": "SAVE_ME"`.
Please have a look at the output example below.

**Output object:**

```
     var output =  [{
        "id": "43", 
        "published": "yes", 
        "publish_date": "20.08.2019",
        "status": "SAVE_ME"
      }, {
        "id": "44",
        "published": "yes", 
        "publish_date": "20.08.2019",
        "status": "SAVED"
     }]
```

I have tried using code below but it does not give me the desired output. It adds only one matching id.

```
            let i = 0;
            firstInput.forEach( function( item ) {         
                 var artikal = item.id; 
                 secondInput.forEach( function( data ) { 
                        if(artikal === data.id_artikla){  
                            firstInput[i].status = "SAVED";  
                        } else { 
                            firstInput[i].status = "SAVE_ME";
                        } 
                     }); 
                i++;
            });
```

Does anyone know how to get the desired output with pure vanilla JS? - Note: the list is 100+ indexes long. Speed is crucial.

Comment: Technically, JSON is when you have serialised a javascript object. As such, you're working with javascript objects, not json.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If both lists are large, you may want to avoid nested loops that compare each item in the first list with every item in the second list, because that would amount to O(n^2) comparisions.

Instead, I'd transform `secondList` into a data structure that supports efficient lookup by id:

```
const articleSaved = {};
for (const item of secondInput) {
    articleSaved[item.id_artikla] = true;
}
for (const item of firstInput) {
    item.status = articleSaved[item.id] ? 'SAVED' : 'SAVE_ME';
}
```

Note that this modifies the existing objects. If you want new objects instead, you could do

```
const result = firstInput.map(item => Object.assign({}, item, {status: saved[item.id] ? 'SAVED' : 'SAVE_ME'}));
```

Comment: Guys thanks for all responses. I will try this now and let you know how it goes. UPDATE: This solution works perfectly. It does have more sense now when I look closer. Thanks for help, cheers @meriton

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `Array.prototype.find()`? This should be a solution to that. [Check this out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: This looks more complex to me to implement with this array I have. But thanks for idea.